# How to copy a file from one location to another in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I got pieces of this code from some of the questions here but I could find none of them to address this specific need. I want to have this program run to log onto a server, copy the xml file in the location set and then update all user profiles with that xml file on all machines in the company. While the code isn't written to go from one server to other machines, I am testing it from one folder location to another on the same machine. However, I get this error, "The target file C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\MyCopyTest is a director, not a file." When I do list the file name I with a different folder, I get the directory created "Test Folder" with another directory inside it called "MyCopyTest.txt"

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;

namespace copy_delete_move_files
{
    public class SimpleFileCopy
    {
        public static object Logger { get; private set; }

        static void Main()
        {
            string fileName = "test.txt";
            string sourcePath = @"C:\Users\Public\Test Folder";
            string targetPath = @"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\SubDir";

            // Use Path class to manipulate file and directory paths.
            string sourceFile = Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);       
            string destFile = Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

            // To copy a folder's contents to a new location:
            // Create a new target folder, if necessary.
            if (!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
            }

            // To copy a file to another location and 
            // overwrite the destination file if it already exists.
            File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);

            // To copy all the files in one directory to another directory.
            // Get the files in the source folder.
            // Note: Check for target path was performed previously
            // in this code example.

            if (Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
            {
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);

                // Copy the files and overwrite destination files if they already exist.
                foreach (string s in files)
                {
                    // Use static Path methods to extract only the file name from the path.
                    fileName = Path.GetFileName(s);
                    destFile = Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
                    File.Copy(s, destFile, true);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Source path does not exist!");
            }

            // Keep console window open in debug mode.
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `sourcePath` should be a directory, but you have a file at the end.  So you in essence are saying `myCopy.txt/myCopy.txt` . Which is not correct.

Comment: @Greg Thank you for the response. I changed the source path to string sourcePath = @"C:\Users\Public\Test Folder"; but I get the error  'The target file "C:\Users\Public\Test Folder" is a directory, not a file.' I want to copy from fileName = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\test.txt"); to the source path.

Comment: Why should your variables `sourceFile` and `destFile` be different? - Your are filling them with identical values.

Comment: You are probably getting the error you mention in the comment, since your `fileName` variable gets empty. My guess would be that your `text.txt` file which you read and fill your `fileName` variable is empty.

Comment: @RandRandom I realized I had sourcePath listed everywhere without a targetPath. I now have the correct code. I will edit and update the code with what I have now. I am now getting an error System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\Users\Public\Test Folder\test.txt' is denied.'. How do I get around this?

Comment: you should try using another folder, not the Users one.

Comment: I got it working. The file it was looking for wasn't in the directory to copy over. It's odd that I got a permissions error rather than couldn't find the sourcePath error.

Answer (score 0):

I had two problems. I didn't have a targetPath written in the code and was therefore trying to copy to the sourcePath. I was able to get it working and then I got a permission denied message for the targetPath. I realized I didn't have the file in the directory for the program to copy to the sourcePath. I fixed that and the program runs perfectly.